# Does XenServer 5.6's pygrub require initrd?

Tags: xenserver, gentoo, paravirtualization

I'm trying to run Gentoo paravirtualized under XenServer 5.6.

Now, Gentoo is perfectly capable of booting without `initrd`, so my question is:

> Do I need an `initrd` for pygrub to work?

Earlier attempts without `initrd` had resulted in errors, which might either be caused by mistakes in `.config` *or* the inexistence of `initrd`. I'm trying to figure out exactly what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After *a lot* of experimentation, I finally found the answer:

> **Yes**, `pygrub` *needs* an initrd/initramfs.

So, I do it this way:

- Build the kernel the manual way `make menuconfig && make && make modules_install`
- Copy the resulting `bzImage` to `/boot`
- Create the initrd using `genkernel --oldconfig ramdisk`
- Feed the path to the kernel and the initrd to `pygrub` from XenServer's console